# VirtualBox or Genymotion Emulator blocks program protocols through host's port proxy

Tags: proxy, port, virtualbox, genymotion

Something blocks program protocols (for example, FTP) when I connect through port proxy to the server (server_ip:port) which was started on Genymotion Android Emulator. TELNET connects to server_ip:port successfully, but the browser or other programs, can't.
Direct connection, not through port proxy, works perfectly.

I switched off an firewalls and an antiviruses ann anythig who can block network data.

Scenario:

1) on the Emulator - start FTP Server of ES Explorer (or any other listening server)

2) on the Host's browser locate - ftp_:_//_emulator_ip_:_emulator_port

3) and successfully operate with emulator files over ftp.

Then I make:

4) on the Host command line - netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 emulator_port emulator_ip emulator_port

5) on the Host - telnet host_ip emulator_port      or     telnet 127.0.0.1 emulator_port

6) and telnet successfully connected

7) on the Host's browser or other ftp-programms - ftp_:_//_host_ip_:_emulator_port_ or ftp_:_//*127.0.0.1*:_emulator_port or ftp_:_//_host_name_:_emulator_port

8) and cannot access FTP service at all

I hade

Who is guilty? VirtualBox or Genymotion Emulator? Who are blocking programm protocols (such as FTP) over port proxy?

What I should do to access Genymotion Emulator via port proxy?

Thank you!

Comment: have you tried forwarding ports ? `adb forward tcp:<host port> tcp:<virtual device port>`